# Data structure to support optimal operations for a scoreboard

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

There is a scoreboard which is required to be maintained and supported by the following two operations:

```
void insert(string playerName, int score);
list<string> getPlayersByRank(int rank);
```

The insert function may insert the playerName along with his score or update the score of the player in the case the player is already present in the scoreboard.

> Provide a data structure to support the above two operations making them as optimal as possible. Both the functions will be called frequently.

Answer (score 2):

Homework?

A balanced binary tree springs to mind, as it gives you O(log(n)) insertion and (O(n)) in-order traversal.

Check out AVL trees, for example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree

*Edit:*

Thanks so tmyklebu's commit, I realized that I overlooked the fact that your `getPlayersByRank` takes a parameter, so it's a lookup by rank instead of a complete traversal.

The approach still works, but you should use a variant where each node knows how many descendants it has in each branch. That way, you can descend directly to the desired rank.

Example:

```
(<P1S1L1R1> = Player 1 Score 1 Left 1 Right 1)

             <P1S6L3R2>
            /            \
      <P2S8L1R1>        <P5S3L0R1>
      /        \           \
<P3S10L0R0>    <P4S8L0R0>    <P6S1L0R0>
```

Now from this tree if you want to get all players ranked 2nd, you would just look at the root and see that there are three left nodes, so the player at the root node (P1) is ranked 4th. You would descend left to P2 and see that there is only one left node, so P2 is ranked 2nd. However, to get all players ranked 2nd you would still need to descend right and find P4 also, who has the same score (assuming that same-scored players are always inserted at the right).

So the current rank of every node is:

```
 (rank of parent node) + (number of left children) 
    + (0 if (score is the same as score of parent node) or
       1 otherwise))
```

When inserting or deleting a node, update the balancing and the weight information (how many left and right children there are). When updating score, delete the node and reinsert with new score.

Comment: You don't want to do inorder traversal, though.  You want to attach an attribute to each node of your tree so that you can select by rank efficiently.

Comment: Thanks, I overlooked that! Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @MikeHartl So, the complexity of the getPlayerByRank operation would be O(n) ? Can the overall complexities of the two functions be improved by choosing some other data structure?

Comment: @Sankalp getPlayerByRank is O(log(n)), like any lookup in a binary search tree. Full traversal (listing all players) would be O(n). Insert is O(log(n)) as well.

Comment: @MikeHartl Be wary of the fact that the scores of certain might be equal, so in the worst case the time complexity of getPlayerByRank operation might be of the order of number of nodes in the BST. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Sankalp Only if all players have the same score, then the correct result of `getPlayerByRank` is the list of all players, so O(n) would be the ideal complexity. So, to be correct, the complexity is O(log(N)) + O(M) where N = number of players and M = number of players with the score which gives the desired rank. There's no time lost though, as every one of these is part of the result.

Comment: @MikeHartl What if a list is maintained for the players with similar scores with the rank of the player pointing to its head. This simulation is actually possible if a sorted hashmap is maintained.

Comment: Note that `insert`, when used for updating, takes in a player's name. So you have to find the player (O(n)), delete him (O(log n)) and then insert him again (O(log n)). Note the O(n) at the beginning -- you can't just do a binary search, since the tree is sorted by rank not player name.

Comment: I'd suggest using a hashtable with the binary tree. You can keep the player's name and their current rank in the hashtable. Looking up the player by name now becomes O(log n): O(1) to look up the rank from the hashtable and O(log n) to traverse to the rank. Deletion and insertion stay O(log n). For both of these operations, you now have to update the hashtable as well, but that's just O(1) and doesn't change the time complexity.

Comment: @Anubhav Can you explain how you are going to leverage binary tree to keep the time complexities upto (log n) ? You have to get the player name by rank.

Comment: @Anubhav: Thanks for the suggestion, I agree, I overlooked the lookup by name. Your proposal makes sense.

Comment: @Anubhav: On second thought, your insert is O(n) as well and not only for update, but also for insert. That is, after inserting, you'd need to update the Hashtable entries for all the players with lower scores. So, instead of keeping the rank in the Hashtable, it should be the score or even a pointer to the actual tree node and we're good.

Comment: @MikeHartl Yep. That's what was bugging me. Keeping the pointer to the actual tree node would solve the problem.

Comment: @MikeHartl D'oh! Yes, I'd keep the score. (Pointers work too, but I don't like that solution. If you think of using pointers, you're thinking about a C/C++ style pointer-based implementation of the BST, while I'm thinking of an abstract conceptual model.)